# disable jquery animation and affects in website

Tags: javascript, performance, web

i want just disable jquery animations and affects in X website, example in gambler sites.

the jquery animations make the betting process slow so i want just turn off jquery and jquery UI animations

i mean any chrome extension to disable jquery or something like that

jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects, widgets, and themes built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for that you can use:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/prop_jquery_fx_off.asp

Comment: yes but i mean turn off this in any website, i am not making any site, i just want disable it in X website on internet.

Comment: In Chrome (other browsers have the same), open DevTools and in the console run the code `jQuery.fx.off = false;` Then if you are willing you could create a Chrome extension or of any browser that do this automatically for a particular website.

Comment: @MasterDJon you need to run `jQuery.fx.off = true` rather

Comment: @r3mark You are right. Probably read too fast the option's description.